# signalflowdiagram does not draw anything with `\matrix`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikzlibrary

I am using `signalflowdiagram` from here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/signal-flow-building-blocks/. Then I installed it in my `texmf-local` folder.  The tree looks like this:

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
tex
├── latex
│   ├── local
│   ├── signalflowlibrary
│   │   ├── macros.sty
│   │   ├── signalflowdiagram.sty
│   │   ├── tikzlibrarysignalflowarrows.code.tex
│   │   ├── tikzlibrarysignalflowblocks.code.tex
│   │   ├── tikzlibrarysignalflowdiagram.code.tex
│   │   └── tikzlibrarysignalflowoperators.code.tex
...
```

After copying the necessary files to the tree as shown above, I ran `$ mktexlsr` to make sure LaTeX can find the new custom package.

I can confirm that it works properly because this code:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}

\begin{document}
  \begin{signalflow}{Block diagram}
    \begin{scope}
      \node[input] (in) {$R(s)$};
      \node[filter] (plant) [right from=in] {$G(s)$};
      \path[r>] (in) -- (plant);
    \end{scope}
  \end{signalflow}
\end{document}
```

produces this picture:

[image]

## The problem

Now I want to position the nodes using `\matrix`. First, I will show that I can get `\matrix` to work, nothing fancy:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]
  {%
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I get this:

[image]

This time, I want to use the predefined blocks in `signalflowdiagram`, so I uncomment the line that says `\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}`.  My code now looks like this. Notice the use of `signalflow` and `scope` environments as shown in the first example above.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{signalflow}{Block diagram}
    \begin{scope}
      \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]
      {%
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
      };
    \end{scope}
  \end{signalflow}
\end{document}
```

Nothing appears :o I have not even started using the predefined blocks in `signalflowdiagram`.

[image]

Even using an ordinary `tikzpicture` draws nothing:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]
    {%
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## The common denominator

As long as `\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}` is present, all `\matrix` disappear.

Is there a way to get `signalflowdiagram` to work with `\matrix`? I did try hacking into the `signalflowdiagram` code files, disabling definition of new environments, etc., to no avail.

Comment: I just looked at the style file and found that the main environment `signalflow` nests `tikzpicture`s. For me, this is enough reason not to use that package. This suggests that the issues you are reporting may only be fixed by rewriting the style file and its libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @marmot's comment, the style file itself is unwieldy. So I hacked it myself here: https://github.com/kitmonisit/signalflow

I'll quote the included example:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{signalflowdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [every node/.style={anchor=center}]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
      minimum width=7.5in,
      row sep=10mm,
      column sep=16mm]
    {%
      % row 0
      \node[input] (in)    {$R(s)$}; &
      \node[adder] (add)   {};       &
      \node[block] (plant) {$G(s)$}; &
      \node[node]  (tap)   {};       &
      \node[output](out)   {$C(s)$}; \\
      % row 1
      &
      &
      \node[block] (fb)    {$H(s)$}; &
      &
      & \\
    };

    \path[r>] (in) -- (add);
    \path[r>] (add) -- (plant);
    \path[r]  (plant) -- (tap);
    \path[r>] (tap) -- (out);
    \path[r>] (tap) |- (fb);
    \path[r>] (fb) -| (add);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: signal flow diagram]